# How to do unit tests with NodeJs (typescript) and Sequelize 5 (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: node.js, api, unit-testing, sequelize.js

I try to build an api with Sequelize 5 but I don't know how to do unit tests. I'm getting the interface tests done. But for example, on my data model I don't know how to do that.

I looked at the "sequelize-test-helpers" npm package but my data model is unarchitected in the same way. So.. do I need to modify the architecture of my code or do you have a solution ?

interface of my location data model :

```
export interface ICoordinates {
    type: string;
    coordinates: number[];
}

export default interface ILocation {
    id: string;
    coordinates: ICoordinates;
    description?: string | undefined | null;
    name: string;
    type_id: number;
    owner: string;
}
```

my location data model :

```
import { sequelize } from '../config/postgres';
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import ILocation, { ICoordinates } from './interfaces/location.interface';

export class Location extends Model implements ILocation {
    public id!: string;
    public coordinates!: ICoordinates;
    public description: string | undefined | null;
    public name!: string;
    public type_id!: number;
    public owner!: string;
}

Location.init({
    id: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false},
    coordinates: { type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT', 4326), allowNull: false },
    description: { type: DataTypes.TEXT},
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    type_id: { type: DataTypes.NUMBER, allowNull: false },
    owner: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull: false }
}, {
    tableName: "location",
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use [jestjs](https://jestjs.io/en/) as the testing framework.

Package versions:

- `"sequelize": "^5.21.3"`
- `"jest": "^24.9.0"`
- `"typescript": "^3.9.6"`
- `"ts-jest": "^24.3.0"`

Unit testing solution:

`interfaces.ts`:

```js
export interface ICoordinates {
  type: string;
  coordinates: number[];
}

export default interface ILocation {
  id: string;
  coordinates: ICoordinates;
  description?: string | undefined | null;
  name: string;
  type_id: number;
  owner: string;
}
```

`model.ts`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import ILocation, { ICoordinates } from './interfaces';

export class Location extends Model implements ILocation {
  public id!: string;
  public coordinates!: ICoordinates;
  public description: string | undefined | null;
  public name!: string;
  public type_id!: number;
  public owner!: string;
}

Location.init(
  {
    id: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false },
    coordinates: { type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT', 4326), allowNull: false },
    description: { type: DataTypes.TEXT },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    type_id: { type: DataTypes.NUMBER, allowNull: false },
    owner: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull: false },
  },
  {
    tableName: 'location',
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
  },
);
```

`db.ts`:

```js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const dotenvConfigOutput = dotenv.config();
if (dotenvConfigOutput.error) {
  console.error(dotenvConfigOutput.error);
  process.exit(1);
}

const envVars = dotenvConfigOutput.parsed!;
console.log(envVars);

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'postgres',
  host: envVars.POSTGRES_HOST,
  username: envVars.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: envVars.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: envVars.POSTGRES_DB,
  port: Number.parseInt(envVars.POSTGRES_PORT, 10),
  define: {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false,
  },
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10 * 1000,
  },
});

export { sequelize };
```

`model.test.ts`:

```js
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

const mSequelize = {};

jest.mock('../../db', () => {
  return { sequelize: mSequelize };
});

const modelStaticMethodMocks = {
  init: jest.fn(),
};

jest.mock('sequelize', () => {
  class MockModel {
    public static init(attributes, options) {
      modelStaticMethodMocks.init(attributes, options);
    }
  }
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('sequelize'),
    Model: MockModel,
  };
});

describe('62584898', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    await import('./model');
    expect(modelStaticMethodMocks.init).toBeCalledWith(
      {
        id: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false },
        coordinates: { type: DataTypes.GEOMETRY('POINT', 4326), allowNull: false },
        description: { type: DataTypes.TEXT },
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        type_id: { type: DataTypes.NUMBER, allowNull: false },
        owner: { type: DataTypes.TEXT, allowNull: false },
      },
      {
        tableName: 'location',
        sequelize: mSequelize,
        timestamps: false,
      },
    );
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/examples/stackoverflow/62584898/model.test.ts
  62584898
    ✓ should pass (463ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 model.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.215s, estimated 5s
```